# itertools: cycle through several lists N times via iteration

Tags: python, python-itertools, cycle

I would like to replace:

```
colors=itertools.cycle(('k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g'))
```

with a more elegant formulation. I tried:

```
colors = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(['k'], 12), itertools.repeat(['b'], 14), itertools.repeat(['g'], 13))
```

but it does not work, how can I do it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Well, what result *do* you get from that attempt? *How is that different* from the working version? The issue is that it simply doesn't "cycle" the values, it just has all the desired values once... right? So. How did you make the values cycle before? By using `itertools.cycle`, right? **What happens if you try** applying that do the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Nah, the first issue is that `itertools.chain.from_iterable` errors because it doesn't take three arguments.

Comment: Oh, there are more problems: 1) `itertools.repeat` should accept **the value** that you want to repeat, not a list containing that value; and 2) `itertools.chain.from_iterable` wants a single iterable (i.e., all the `itertools.repeat` objects *in a list*, not as separate arguments) - to pass separate arguments as you're trying, you just want `itertools.chain`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was in the middle of figuring that out. :)

Comment: Anyway: there are *multiple* issues here, and *all* of them are typos: that is to say, they are addressed by *going back to the place* where you found out that there is such a thing as `itertools.repeat` etc. in the first place (the *documentation*), and *reading more carefully*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way:

```
from itertools import cycle

colors = cycle('k'*12 + 'b'*14 + 'g'*13)
```

(If your strings aren't just single characters, wrap them in lists like `['k']*12`.)

With more itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle, repeat, chain, starmap

spec = ('k', 12), ('b', 14), ('g', 13)
colors = chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, cycle(spec)))
```

```
from itertools import cycle, repeat, chain, starmap

spec = ('k', 12), ('b', 14), ('g', 13)
colors = cycle(chain(*starmap(repeat, spec)))
```

Test at [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZIxbgMhEEWllJxiOsOGRLu2Czc-i8UivEZhFwRjKT6LGzfJbXKBnCYD2FGUJrGTYqQv9IH3v-b4Gg6489Pp9LLH7cPq_e5tG_0IFk1E710COwYfEfRBOyMhmmAUStA7ZScJNjmr6TihiqMKjDHtnY8J1vUC57Onmbxq-htnuHqEYMw8B6ORcJ1NyGscXjNI6Nq2zSaWyESeEga6uZAk-yyXRQ5ZLsSX7Lmdx1zkJhepemriXBH_bLD0k18W-Y9o0t79ABKinZBfnGuo8DcBls8LJm--k_0z0y9hCL3p5nAP5G26ZRYDicXfOOpWn5f7suQf)